# Difference between _ptr, _pointer, and _cpointer in Racket's FFI

Tags: pointers, racket, ffi

The Racket FFI's documentation has types for [`_ptr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/foreign_procedures.html?q=_ptr#%28form._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe..rkt%29.__ptr%29%29), [`_cpointer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/foreign_tagged-pointers.html?q=_cpointer#%28def._%28%28lib._ffi%2Funsafe..rkt%29.__cpointer%29%29), and [`_pointer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/Pointer_Types.html?q=_pointer#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25foreign%29.__pointer%29%29).<sup>1</sup>

However, the documentation (as of writing this question) does not seem to compare the three different types. Obviously the first two are functions that produce `ctype?`s, where as the last one is a `ctype?` itself. But when would I use one type over the other?

<sub><sup>1</sup>It also has as other types such as `_box`, `_list`, `_gcpointer`, and `_cpointer/null`. These are all variants of those three functions.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `_ptr` is a macro that is used to create types that are suitable for function types in which you need to pass data via a pointer passed as an argument (a very common idiom in C).
- `_pointer` is a generic pointer ctype that can be used pretty much wherever a pointer is expected or returned. On the Racket side, it becomes an opaque value that you can't manipulate very easily (you can use `ptr-ref` if you need it). Note the docs have some caveats about interactions with GC when using this.
- `_cpointer` constructs safer variants of `_pointer` that use tags to ensure that you don't mix up pointers of different types. It's generally more convenient to use `define-cpointer-type` instead of manually constructing these. In other words, these help you build abstractions represented by Racket's C pointers. You can do it manually with `cpointer-push-tag!` and `_pointer` but that's less convenient.

There's also a blog post I wrote that goes into more detail about some of these pointer issues: http://prl.ccs.neu.edu/blog/2016/06/27/tutorial-using-racket-s-ffi/